# How to erase a circle in core-graphics

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, core-graphics

I am developing a drawing app using Core-Graphics. For the eraser I used `kCGBlendModeClear`. It erases my drawing in a square shape. Here is the code:

```
         context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
         CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context,self.red,self.green,self.blue,1);
         CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
         CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
         CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.eraserWidth);
         CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
         CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, YES);
         CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, YES);
```

How can I make the stroke round instead of square ?

Comment: Please make your question little more understandable.

Comment: Is the background of the app white ? Why no tjust set the stroke color to a white color CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context,1,1,1,1);

Comment: "How can I make the stroke round instead of square ?
Is it so difficult to formulate a correct question? Do you want rounded corners at the rectangle, or do youwant to add a circle to the path?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make the stroke round instead of square ?

If you meant adding a circle to the path:

```
CGContextAddEllipseInRect()
```

If you meant that the outer border of an rectangle (or other line joins)  has rounded joins, set

```
CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
```